# How Can i read mifare classic 1k Card by Nexus s

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

am working with NFC Android programming and I want to read Mifare Classic cards. Does anybody know how to read the sectors off such a card?

Authentication method returns true which means that authentication is done. After authentication, sector should be ready for any IO action but whenever i use readBlock() method or transceive() method, I get exception with IOException("transceive failed"). I can not find any example which uses the Mifare Classic, so i want to know if it is possible to read the Mifare Classic with this API or not.

My code like this `boolean success = m1tag.authenticateSectorWithKeyB(0,MifareClassic。KEY_DEFAULT）
int index = m1tag.sectorToBlock(0)
byte[] content = m1tag.readBlock(index)`

success is true,but when i read content from card,throw IOException("transceive failed")

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to `readBlock()` or `writeBlock()` after using `authenticateSectorWithKeyB()`.
If it is a new tag with default access bits access to the tag will be blocked. If the access conditions have be changed then `readBlock()` and `writeBlock()` will throw an exception. You will have to perform reading of the tag using KeyA authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read the Block of a mifare card by authonticating with keyB.
To read the block of Mifare card, you will have to aunthenticae with key A i.e. use `authenticateSectorWithKeyA()` instead of `authenticateSectorWithKeyB()`.

Comment: That is not true. Depending on the access control configuration of the blocks in the sector trailer, key B can be used to read blocks. However, the default configuration from the manufacturer ("empty card") is such that key B cannot be used to read the blocks.

Comment: @NFCguy Can you please provide your valuable opinion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220523/card-emulation-via-software-nfc